# Omission of "and" in headlines

Tags: conjunctions, headline-english, asyndeton

What is this phenomenon called?

Is it common in all English-speaking countries?

Comment: This is a partial duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/whats-with-syntax-in-newspaper-headlines .

Answer (score 11):

The omission of conjunctions is officially called ***asyndeton***. Greek *deo* = "to tie, to bind" (just like Latin *iungo* in *conjunction*); *syn* = "together (with)"; *a* = "non-". A *syndeton* is a conjunction; *asyndeton* is "non-conjunction". That is what the omission of conjunctions for rhetorical effect or otherwise has been called since Antiquity.

I believe it is quite common in most European languages, both in headlines for brevity and in literature as a figure of speech. It can also be a natural and quite neutral feature of ordinary texts, with hardly any special effect. You will find it in speech as well.

Comment: +1 for dipping into that big grab-bag of rhetorical devices. I'll only add that according to Farnsworth, the connection of items "by commas alone may emphasize the relationships between them ... [and] create a sense of acceleration" suitable for a news headline.

Comment: The use of commas in headlines to replace "and" is far more common in the US than the UK (though it is on the increase there too). I found it very confusing the first few times I came across it...

Answer (score 4):

Headlines, like speech, tweets, and book titles, are often not made of full, grammatical sentences. It's a method of saving space while retaining readability; the "and" is usually replaced by a comma, as in "Site Answers Questions about Cooking, English, Gaming".