# Omitting "and" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, asyndeton

> He called her, emailed her, texted her, tweeted her—all to no use.

Strictly speaking, I would need to write *texted her **and** tweeted her*, but I'm omitting *and* to convey a rhythm and sense of urgency. What do you call this kind of construction, and is it accepted grammar (at least for creative writing, if not in an academic context)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Omission of "and" in headlines](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15266/omission-of-and-in-headlines)

Comment: @Cerberus: That question is about telegraphese in headlines; this one is about prose. Similar, but definitely distinct.

Comment: @Jon: Okay, it is about a different context; but it does lead to similar answers. Perhaps more could be said about this, though I am not sure what...

Comment: "all to no use" doesn't sound right. Did you mean "all to no avail"?

Comment: @GrahamBorland I think "all to no use" sounds fine, although "all to no avail" is the more common usage.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a rhetorical device called **asyndeton**, and you can find its definition (as well as those of other rhetorical figures) [here](http://www.virtualsalt.com/rhetoric.htm#Asyndeton).

> **Asyndeton** consists of omitting conjunctions between words, phrases, or clauses. In a list of items, asyndeton gives the effect of unpremeditated multiplicity, of an extemporaneous rather than a labored account: *On his return he received medals, honors, treasures, titles, fame.*

Comment: Right. The device here conveys speed and urgency. Very appropriate to the subject matter in question.

Comment: I love that not only is it a valid device, but it has a name.  This site is great!

Comment: +1 for the link.  I usually use the much more [extensive list of literary terms available here](http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/lit_terms_A.html).

Answer (score 3):

I was taught that omitting the 'and' in such a situation was completely acceptable, especially in creative writing. The rhythm is much better without it. Leave it as is.

Comment: Not only that, It seems it is acceptable in a New York Times editorial. "...his entire career makes a mockery of faith, family, tradition, virtue." https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/08/opinion/sunday/the-west-and-what-comes-after.html?_r=0

Comment: 'I came, I saw[,] and I conquered.' Not quite as punchy.