# Phrase for the construction "a, b, c, and d"

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for a concise phrase for the sentence construction "a, b, c, and d".  That is, a comma-separated list of things, where the last comma is either replaced or accompanied by the word "and".

Comment: What's wrong with *list*?

Comment: @TimLymington "list" is too generic.  The specific action I'm looking for is a transformation from a simple comma separated list to one with an "and" before the last element.

Comment: Actually, *list* is precise and specific in describing the thing you say you want described.

Comment: @Robusto I disagree. "a, b, c, d" is a list.  So is "a, b, c, and d".  I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes the latter construction but NOT the former.

Comment: A comma-separated list of things, where the last comma is either replaced or accompanied by the word "and".

Comment: Not a fan of the general attitude of this stackexchange site

Comment: So that is what you are asking? Then this is [a dupe](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15970/omitting-and-in-a-sentence/15973#15973) in sheep's clothing.

Comment: How about "a standard enumeration"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The specific action I'm looking for is a transformation from a simple comma separated list to one with an "and" before the last element.

Not using *and* in a list is called [**asyndeton**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/asyndeton).

Such a list is styled *asyndetic* and the action of adding an *and* might be called *syndetication*, although I can't find a reference for that.

Using *and* between every element in a list ("a and b and c and d", in the manner of excited children) is called *polysyndeton* — that's listed in OED but not ODO.

I suppose a list with just one conjunction might be termed ***monosyndetic.*** I can't find a reference for that either.

Comment: Rather than *syndetication*, you can just say the construction is a *syndeton*, which is well-attested. *Monosyndeton* is also found in linguistic works like [this](http://depts.washington.edu/uwwpl/vol24/pub_submission_Drellishak.pdf).

Comment: good answer. coordination without a conjunction can also be called *asyndetic coordination*, and coordination with a conjunction is called *syndetic coordination*.

Answer (score 1):

I would just call that a [*series.*](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/commas/comma-before-and/) (This is also why the Oxford comma is sometimes called [a serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).)