# Is there a name for this literary device from James Baldwin and question about punctuation?

Tags: punctuation, literature, literary-techniques, literary-device

In James Baldwin's essay Everybody's Protest Novel, there is the following sentence:

> It must be remembered that the oppressed and the oppressor are bound together within **the same** society; **they** accept **the same** criteria, **they** share **the same** beliefs, **they** both alike depend on **the same** reality.

I know that repeating the word or phrase at the beginning of a clause is called *anaphora*. In this case, that word is "they." Also, I know that repeating the last word or phrase in a clause is called *epistrophe*. Now, **is there a name for repeating a word or phrase in the middle of a clause** as is the case with "the same" in the sentence above.

Related to the same sentence, the short independent clauses after the semicolon are separated by commas and there is not coordinating conjunction. Is this common grammatical practice or not?

EDIT: The second part of the question has already been answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15970/omitting-and-in-a-sentence).

Comment: [Parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(rhetoric)) generally, or [mesodiplosis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/M/mesodiplosis.htm) more narrowly, and  [asyndeton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton).

Comment: mesodiplosis, that's exactly what I was looking for @StoneyB. Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I'd just call it *repetition*.

Answer (score 3):

Betwen Anaphora(repetition of the beginning of a sentence) and Epistrophe(repetition of the end of a sentence), consider **Anadiplosis** (*and of course "mesodisplosis" proposed by @StoneyB*),

> [Anadiplosis](https://mcl.as.uky.edu/glossary-rhetorical-terms#top) ("doubling back") the rhetorical repetition of one or
>   several words; specifically, repetition of a word that ends one clause
>   at the beginning of the next.
>
> *Men in great place are thrice servants: servants of the sovereign or state; servants of fame; and servants of business*. Francis Bacon

Anaphora and Epistrophe: [Two Rhetorical Devices You See Everywhere](http://thewritepractice.com/anaphora-and-epistrophe-two-rhetorical-devices-you-see-everywhere)