# Confused about the following list

Tags: commas, lists

"The lessons coming out of Baltimore, the lessons coming out of France's large cities, the lessons coming out of all our societies show that neighbourhoods matter, place matters, where you live matters." - Tharman Shanmugaratnam

The author has used the phrase "the lessons coming out of" three times. Which set of rules make the last two grammatically correct? Why is there not an "and" between "place matters" and "where you live matters"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list separated by commas with no "and" at the end](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420449/list-separated-by-commas-with-no-and-at-the-end). Lists should include 'and' before the last item in formal writing, but omitting this is becoming more and more an accepted style choice in (I'd say often good) not-ultraformal writing. This enhances a 'running', flowing, smooth style, when pauses would detract. As mentioned at the duplicate thread, there are other options. // As the usage is (in the main) ...

Comment: quite recent, whether or not to include a comma after the last list item is, like the choice to drop the 'and', a judgement call for the author. They may choose different approaches in different situations. And, as hinted at, they have other punctuation (for instance, ellipses) available. // If this is the original rather than a translation, it may be worth considering that Tharman Shanmugaratnam was educated at Harvard and Cambridge, and is an Honorary Fellow of LSE.

Comment: I agree with the above but I also think it maks a huge difference if you repeat e.g. *the lessons*. If that appeared only once I think you'd be much more likely to find *and*. On top of that, the semicolon is not much used theae days, and although some people use a dash instead, many just use a comma. The comma  sometimes serves as an ellipsis too, and with so many roles its usage is bound to be complicated. The sentence above has the form *if you look at x... if you look at Y... wherever you look, you see Z*. All of which to say I am not sure it is a typical list.

Comment: There are many posts here referring to *asyndeton.* It's a common-enough rhetorical device, and because it's a rhetorical device it's more likely to feature deliberately in more formal writing than less formal, surely.

Comment: There is absolutely no rule that says you can't repeat information. By some lights, repetition could be considered *better* because there is less room for ambiguous interpretation. However, stylistically, it also sometimes sounds more awkward. In *this* case, I think the repetition has a good effect because it serves to emphasize the idea being expressed (although I would put a comma after *societies*).