# Is "happened Tuesday" (without "on") a valid pattern?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, time

> The album was **released Tuesday** and has been well-received by […]

Shouldn't it be "**released *on* Tuesday**"?  Where did the "**on**" go?

I think dropping the preposition is confusing, but I see it written and said so frequently (with clearly the same intended meaning) that I'm doubtful whether I should be correcting it.

Is this pattern valid English?  Is it region-specific?  Does it have a name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it common to omit a preposition (in / on / of) before “the month (year / week /day) when they are used adjectively and adverbially?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111217/is-it-common-to-omit-a-preposition-in-on-of-before-the-month-year-week)

Comment: @Edwin Thanks; that's exactly what I meant. It's pretty hard to search for!

Comment: This is unexceptionable in AmE, but not universally accepted in BrE, though the acceptance is growing due to constant exposure to American movies etc.

Comment: I agree. Only people who haven't bothered to search should take a 'duplicate closure' as a reproof; a lot of the success in searching boils down to the individual memories of long-time contributors here (tchris is wondrously gifted and a most valuable asset). Always ask after say 5 minutes; use pooled memories.