# Is the omission of the preposition before the day of the week grammatically correct when the noun is directly preceded by a verb?

Tags: prepositions

I have seen the sentence structure *verb + day of the week* (which skips the usual "on" preposition splitting the phrase) appearing here and there, e.g., [in CNN's article](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/12/20/health/us-coronavirus-monday/index.html) noted below:

> The Omicron Covid-19 variant is now the most dominant strain in the US, accounting for over 73% of new coronavirus cases less than three weeks after the first was reported, according to estimates **posted Monday** by the US Centers for Disease Control and Prevention.

I would like to know why the word "Monday" is not preceded by the preposition "on". I have seen [an answer to a similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111232), however, none of the reasons stated in the reply applies to the case I outlined. Is such use of English considered to be grammatically correct?

Comment: From my experience, it seems to be normal in American writing. If I found it in British writing, I would regard it as an Americanism.

Comment: @ColinFine — and then again, perhaps it's just one of the many trends that catch on. Have you any evidence to back up your claim that it's an Americanism?

Comment: Yes, now I look. Searching the GloWbE corpus for "verb-ed Tuesday" I find 1743 instances in US sources, against 261 in UK sources. (Canada is in the middle, with 700, and all other English speaking regions are lower). For "verb-ed on Tuesday" the totals are 412 US:672 UK. If I look specifically at "posted [on] Tuesday", the figures without "on" are 8:9 (ie. effectively equal small numbers) but with "on" they are 1 US : 90 UK!