# Is it gramatically correct to omit the preposition "on" when talking about events occuring on a certain day?

Tags: prepositions, omissibility

I'm taking [this online course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/sciwrite) on technical writing. It [suggests](https://www.coursera.org/learn/sciwrite/lecture/nORC2/1-5-cut-the-clutter-more-tricks) that you can omit "on" from

> The meeting happened on Monday

to turn it to

> The meeting happened Monday

The second one seems wrong to me, and I haven't seen it being commonly used either.

Comment: Why should it "seem wrong" just because it's less common?

Comment: Related / Possible Duplicate: Is it common to omit a preposition (*in / on / of*) before “the month (year / week /day) when they are used adjectively and adverbially?
  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/111217/14666

Comment: See also: US news articles missing out “on” when referring to a day
 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/34231/14666

Comment: As a British English speaker I would be much less likely to omit the "on" when talking about the past than when talking about the future. For example I would almost always say "I was talking to John on Monday" but would quite commonly say "I'll see you Monday, then". Having said that it's very informal and I would be unlikely to write it down. I would also be less likely to omit the "on" when speaking of a place or an event. "I'll be in Lincoln Monday" or "My car's in for service Wednesday" are used but are less common than "I'll see you Monday".

Comment: I have seen many times, news and media do gramatical mistakes. So i would not rely on them for learning english. Rather strictly viewing by gramatical sense, is omiting certain words correct?

Comment: @Kris why shouldn't I be skeptical if I haven't seen it being used before? What's the harm in confirming  if it's correct before you start using it?

Comment: @Kris Thanks, I found my answer here https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34233 . Voting to close this as duplicate