# Whether "on" is necessary in this case

Tags: grammar

I am wondering which one below is grammatical:

- I sing a song every ride.
- I sing a song on every ride.

So I guess the question boils down to whether "on every ride" servers as a preposition here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Recurrent units of time do not need a preposition:

- I wake up every *morning*.
- I work every *day*.
- I sleep every *night*.
- Take one pill every *hour*.

Your second sentence is definitely correct, and the first one is, at worst, only incorrect in a pedantic sense because it treats a ride as a time-signifying recurrence; it is essentially saying, "I sing a song **every time I take a ride**."

- We argue every meal.
- We argue *during* every meal.
- We sat next to each other every bus ride.
- We sat next to each other *on* every bus ride.

In each case, the second sentence is more strictly correct than the first, but they are both completely understandable. I would see them as differences in style.

Omitting the preposition is more common in American English than other dialects. [See this question about omitting prepositions of time in American English.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34231/us-news-articles-missing-out-on-when-referring-to-a-day)