# Why in error messages verb 'be' is not used?

Tags: computing, headline-english

In the computer world error messages are written without verb 'be'. For example,

> - file not found,
> - file not exist,
> - command not found,
> - no such file or directory

and so on.
So why verb 'be' is being missed?

**UPD**
My question is duplicate. See ["not found" or "is not found"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73361/not-found-or-is-not-found?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Because the video screen is only 40 characters wide.

Comment: Because it saves space. Compare "файл не найден" with "файл не был найден" -  "File not found" -  "File was not found"  you save a verb and therefore space

Comment: It seems to me no sence to save a few spaces when a file name can be very long.

Comment: Although it sounds reasonable

Comment: And let's not forget that the entire program, including all error messages, must fit on a 180K diskette.

Comment: The program is expressing the error condition as identified through an,  error code through a list of messages already stored Of course person writing the list will write the error string per se without making it look like such a string was generated in real time.

Comment: ..hence when a particular file is not found -- it is ' File not found' error - and a message displayed accordingly. Saying it is 'File is not found' error will be semantically incorrect.

Comment: This practice predates computers - cf. `Address Unknown`.

Comment: Computers (memory and storage, including file names) used to be very limited w/r/t space.  19th century: Morse code.  Telegrams: charged by the word.  Road signs: NO RIGHT ON RED. Also SLOW CHILDREN. Emergency signalling: SOS.