# The elevator going up/down

Tags: gerunds, continuous-aspect

I was very surprised when I first heard "this elevator going up". But then I heard it in a bunch of other places, so it is not a mistake. So, why is it not "the elevator is going up/down"?

Thank you!
Cheers

Comment: This is not a "mistake", as it is intentional, but it isn't normal grammar either. It is "telegraphic style" used only in certain contexts where complete sentences are not necessary. Other similar questions: [Why is it accepted for science journals to write “discussion period open until …”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/247518), [“not found” or “is not found”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/73361), [Why in error messages verb 'be' is not used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/368421), [Why “message sent” and not “message was sent”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/365697)

Comment: @sumelic - Well said. Also, we understand which direction the elevation was headed, without every word explicit. And time is short in such circumstances, hence the condensed telegraph.