# What does your sense of language tell you about this blog post title?

Tags: computing, titles

The title is "Boiling React Down to Few Lines in jQuery".

Is it confusing? Is it appealing or bringing attention? Does it feel wrong? And last, are there anything grammatically wrong with it?

Please state whether you are a native speaker in your answer.

**P.S.** I ask in a such a weird way 'cause grammar could be googled to an extent and I am trying to tap into your sense of language instead.

Comment: If you're writing a headline or title for a story or post, be very careful not to cause [a Crash Blossom](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?cat=118).

Comment: "Boiling React down to **a** Few Lines **using** jQuery". "Using jQuery to boil React down to just a few lines".

Comment: I would interpret it as meaning that "React" (which is presumably some web application concept/function) is "boiled down" (reduced to essence) by a few lines of code written in the *jQuery* language.  (I speak native geek.)

Comment: @HotLicks _To_, not _by_; but otherwise, that’s how I’d parse it, too. “Boiling down to few lines” still sounds very odd to me, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - "Boil down" is a fairly common metaphor used to mean "reduce", or "produce a summary", or "calculate the 'bottom line'".  I don't find its use at all unusual in the above context.

Comment: (The metaphor is of processing maple syrup or making jelly or some similar cooking activity where large volumes of dilute liquid are boiled until a concentrated product is produced.  It's a metaphor which would be meaningful to just about anyone in the US who was born prior to maybe 1960, even without prior exposure to its metaphorical use.)

Comment: @HotLicks I don’t find _boil down_ unusual—it’s the phrase _few lines_ that makes it awkward, with or without an article, though less so with the article, and even less so if we say “boil down to _just_ a few lines”. (And the metaphor should be meaningful to just about anyone born anywhere in the world, even nowadays—if it’s not, they need some basic home ed teachin’s!)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Well, it's a *title* -- articles in titles are often omitted to conserve space.  (And I suspect the meaning may be lost on some of the microwave generation.)

Comment: @HotLicks True, but with _few_ there’s a substantial difference in meaning between the articled and the unarticled version. Even in a title, I would personally prefer to skirt the issue entirely and say “Minimising _React_ code with/in jQuery” or something along those lines instead.

Comment: Whether it's "Confusing", "appealing", "attention-getting" or it "feels wrong" are all opinion-based. The only question which is on-topic is "Is there anything grammatically wrong with it," and we already have [a question on headline syntax](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/why-do-newspaper-headlines-use-strange-syntax-rules).

Comment: @AndrewLeach, even that question falls afoul of the "too-generic proofreading request", I think.

Comment: I don't get the point of this question. Is it about a particular grammar aspect? Do you want it written for non-natives? Are you writing it or just wondering about an existing blog title? Do _you_ find something wrong with it?

Comment: @Mitch added P.S. explaining why I ask weird questions.

Comment: Suor, the PS did not clarify the question. I'll just answer then. Change 'react' to 'reaction', if you are trying to simplify: "I am trying to boil down the reaction to a few lines in jQuery". Titles are in headlinese, so you don't really need the 'a' or 'the'.

Comment: @Mitch React is a name of JavaScript framework http://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Suor: Oh. Well, my fault then. But for those less knowledgeable, quotes would have helped with that. And then 'a few' might make things sound smoother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare with

- Boiling the new taxation bill down to a few lines with respect to the US Constitution.
- Boiling his mental illness down to a few lines in layman's terms.
- Boiling the chemistry of valency down to few lines of quantum mechanics.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is JavaScript library of routines commonly used by other JavaScript libraries as well as directly used by many browser-side UI developers.

React, AngularJS and Ember are JavaScript libraries for implementing higher abstract UI concepts. They depend on, or compete with, jQuery on their low level JavaScript operations.

*Boiling* is a quaintly used word for the act of creating [boilerplates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_%28text%29), but due to rarity of such usage, I am unable to produce evidence of such usage.

*Boiling-down* is the act of reduction of a mass down to its basic non-ethereal entities or concepts. e.g., It all boils down to the govt needing more money. The stew boiled down to few pieces of chicken bones.

Therefore, "Boiling React down to few lines in jQuery" is either, or combination of,

- Reducing the need to use React, by using a few lines of JQuery.
- Reducing the mass of React down to the equivalent of a few lines of JQuery.
- For those familiar with JQuery, explaining what *React* does by substituting *React* calls with a few lines *JQuery* calls.
- How to call *React* using a few lines of jQuery calls.

*Calling* a function or operation is code written to jump into the entry-points of functions or operation of libraries, by transferring a payload of data into the function/operation thro those entrypoints.

---

[boil down](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boil+down)

vb (adverb)

1. (Chemistry) to reduce or be reduced in quantity and usually altered in consistency by boiling: to boil a liquid down to a thick glue.
2. boil down to
   a. (intr) to be the essential element in something
   b. (tr) to summarize; reduce to essentials

*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There are few more specific things I am interested in. 1. Is writing "in jQuery" is ok if I mean jQuery as a kind of language? Or it's too confusing and I better go with "of" or "using"? 2. Is inserting a word between "Boiling" and "down" correct? Shouldn't I wrote that as "Boiling down React ... "?