# How to interpret the sentence "Rahul Dravid appointed head coach of Indian cricket team"?

Tags: grammar, sentence, sentence-meaning

Above mentioned sentence is a News headline.

If i had to write it, I write it as

> Rahul Dravid is appointed as head coach of Indian cricket team.

Where it should be 'is appointed'. How do I understand the original sentence?

Comment: It's a headline, so brevity is the norm. BTW you would write (as a non-headline) "of **the** Indian cricket team."

Comment: This is news-headline style. You have the meaning just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do newspaper headlines use strange syntax rules?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/why-do-newspaper-headlines-use-strange-syntax-rules)